# Does startup.cs gets to be executed once only?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to put a break point and It was only triggered after the first request was made.

[image]

It says on the auto generated comment that it is `per request`.

Are they still executed for the subsequent requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does startup.cs gets to be executed once only?

No. Startup.cs gets called once after every time the application pool recycles.

> It says on the auto generated comment that it is per request.

No, the comment states that it is configuring a single instance of those services "per request", not that the current method runs "per request".

Answer (score 5):

`Startup.cs` is the equivalent to `Application_Start` in global.asax. That is, yes, it only gets executed once per application lifecycle.

What you have highlighted is *setting up* that these items are recreated per request. Those lines are not, themselves, re-executed every request.

Comment: Hey Obsidian, per request of what exactly?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta per discrete call to your api/website.